# How Can I Edit a .txt file using Javascript or jQuery forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, text-files

I have a .txt file that needs to be accessed offline in the browser. Ideally I would like to the page to open and different form fields display the data from each specific line.

Are there any tuts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [Mozilla's explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications) of the HTML 5 File API.

Comment: Thanks but this is a little too risky. There will be multiple people using this and I think relying html5 might cause an issue

Comment: You can't do it 100% client-side without HTML 5 or something similar, like Google Gears.

Comment: unfortunately I don't think that will work as it will be working offline in a file folders. I was hoping for a javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer following documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/FileGuide/FileWriting)